# La Befana - Gene Wolf

Tags: alternate-history

In 2015 I asked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/89846/45698) which allowed me to identify a short story as being "La Befana" by Gene Wolf.

I would like to share the written version of this story with some friends as an interesting "Christmas story".

I'd ask Gene Wolfe for permission if I could, but sadly, he died in 2019 (aged 87).
There are a number of free-to-listen-to audio versions of this story on web. I have not been able to find a text source. I have a copy of a book with the story in "somewhere". When I finish my 35+ year cleanup it may have turned up. At present I do not know where it is in my extensive 'collection'.

I realise that this is not a legal opinions group, but I was hoping people here may be able to give me guidelines on the following.

- Does anyone know of an online source of the text.
- What is the legality of sharing a text version of a story that multiple free audio copies of exist?
- I assume that my making a transcript from an audio version as above has the same legal status

---

Audio version

[Gene Wolfe literary podcast](https://www.stitcher.com/show/the-gene-wolfe-literary-podcast/episode/ep-81-la-befana-64600462)

Same - different site [here](https://www.claytemplemedia.com/post/the-gene-wolfe-literary-podcast-la-befana-with-special-guest-c-michael-morrison)

[Microphones of madness](https://mnh.podbean.com/e/microphones-of-madness-christmas-storytime-gene-wolfes-la-befana/)

Comment: This question isn't about Science Fiction or Fantasy, it's about literary copyright law.

Comment: You' might be better asking this on Law:SE or Literature:SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archive.org has it online as part of the January 1973 issue of Galaxy Magazine, here: https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v33n04_1973-01/page/n73/mode/2up

Note that just because something is on archive.org doesn't necessarily mean it's free from copyright - their FAQ says

> Some of the content available through the Archive may be governed by local, national, and/or international laws and regulations, and your use of such content is solely at your own risk. You agree to abide by all applicable laws and regulations, including intellectual property laws, in connection with your use of the Archive. In particular, you certify that your use of any part of the Archive's Collections will be limited to noninfringing or fair use under copyright law. If a Creative Commons or other license has been declared for particular material on the Archive, to the extent you trust the declaration and declarer (which is rarely the Internet Archive), you may use the content according to the terms and conditions of the applicable license.

You'd be better to ask at Law Stack Exchange for your copyright question.

Comment: Not a great idea to answer questions that are clearly off-topic.

Comment: @Valorum I just read the cited help centre info plus that on related links. My first question is not covered either in the permitted or prescribed categories. I own a copy of the related material, as I noted, but do not presently know where it is. Thanks to Showsni's most welcom input I can tick off the first question, and ponder the legal ramifications which would have applied if I'd found my copy.